# How to prevent Overloading?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to prevent overloading of user defined functions in C++? Suppose I have a function as:

```
void foo(int , int);
```

Can I prevent foo from being overloaded, and if so how? If I can, can this be extended to prevent overriding of the methods through inheritance?

Comment: Please tell us, why do you want to prevent others from overloading it?

Comment: I sense some confusion here: overloading has nothing to do with inheritance and overriding, they are totally different beasts.

Comment: I don't see confused ideas here, so I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: I think litb's comment has the key to a solution to your problem: Tell us about your actual problem, instead of asking us about an attempt to a solution you came up with. Why do you (think you) need that? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: There is still the function reference way: `namespace fn { void foo(int, int); } void (&foo)(int, int) = fn::foo;`. Now "foo" cannot be "overloaded". But of course this is just as ugly and doesn't prolly solve the "real" problem

Answer (score 12):

In a word: no.  You can't prevent an overload of `foo` being defined with a different signature somewhere else and you also can't prevent virtual functions from being overriden.

In the C++ world you have to give some degree of trust to people writing code that winds up in your program.

Comment: This might be a very dumb question......i am still learning C++. How did the designer of c++ prevent certain operators from being overloaded?

Comment: Well, if you invent the language, you get to make the rules. Is that what you meant?

Comment: With lots of hard work in the C++ working group? (I don't think I understand what you're driving at.)

Comment: Bjarne Stroustrup designed what became C++, wrote the first C++ compiler, and stayed active in the development of the language.  You make up your own language that becomes wildly popular, and you can decide what gets overloaded.  In fact, there is a list of operators in the standard, and a list of what cannot be overloaded, and it's up to the compiler writers to enforce that.

Comment: I think it's built into the compiler that attempts to overload operators for primitive types is automatically an error. Built-in operators are not same as overloaded operators (not a function, logical operators have short-circuiting, some operators cannot be overloaded at all etc).

Comment: Part of C++'s pecularities are for C compatibility, and the built-in versions of many operators fall into this category as well. E.g. operator+(int, char*).

Answer (score 6):

Section 13.1.1 through 13.1.3 of the standard describe the kinds of functions that can *not* be overloaded:

> Certain function declarations cannot be overloaded:
>
> - Function declarations that differ only in the return type cannot be overloaded.
> - Member function declarations with the same name and the same parameter types cannot be overloaded if any of them is a static member function declaration (9.4).
>
> Note: as specified in 8.3.5, function declarations that have equivalent parameter declarations declare the same function and therefore cannot be overloaded:
>
> - Parameter declarations that differ only in the use of equivalent typedef “types” are equivalent. A typedef is not a separate type, but only a synonym for another type (7.1.3).
> - Parameter declarations that differ only in a pointer * versus an array [] are equivalent. That is, the array declaration is adjusted to become a pointer declaration (8.3.5). Only the second and subsequent array dimensions are significant in parameter types (8.3.4).
> - Parameter declarations that differ only in that one is a function type and the other is a pointer to the same function type are equivalent. That is, the function type is adjusted to become a pointer to function type (8.3.5).
> - Parameter declarations that differ only in the presence or absence of const and/or volatile are equivalent. That is, the const and volatile type-specifiers for each parameter type are ignored when determining which function is being declared, defined, or called.
> - Two parameter declarations that differ only in their default arguments are equivalent.

Otherwise, the function *can* be overloaded, and **there is no way to prevent that.**

Answer (score 3):

You cannot.

Answer (score 2):

Make it a static function in a class and tell people not to modify that class?

Answer (score 0):

This can be simulated by making it a `struct` instance:

```cpp
struct foo_t {
    void operator()(int, int);
} foo;

// error: redefinition of 'foo' as different kind of symbol
void foo(double, double);
```

or a function reference:

```cpp
void foo_impl(int, int);
auto const& foo = foo_impl;

// error: redefinition of 'foo' as different kind of symbol
void foo(double, double);
```

Answer (score -1):

Do what UncleBens said, *and* include in the class a constant which is an encrypted checksum of the text in the class, and a function to test it for validity. That way, nobody can change the class. Just a thought (maybe not a very good one).

As I think about it, that's pretty dumb because the class would need its own text. However, as an alternative, it could read its compiled binary code, and have a checksum for that. I'm getting out on a limb here.

Comment: The class' binary code (whatever that, how do you untangle the binary mess an optimizing compiler leaves behind?) would have to include that constant. Talk about recursion.

Comment: @sbi: yeah, but it's a standard trick in the embedded world to checksum the binary, if only to detect memory corruption.

Answer (score -2):

The only reasonable way would be to give the function C linkage:

```
extern "C" void foo(int , int);
```

This works because with C linkage, names aren't mangled, so you can't do any overloading (which relies on encoding the types of arguments into the symbol name).

Obviously this won't extend to member functions.

Comment: This does not really prevent others from writing `void foo(int) { }` right next to it though.

Comment: You can only have one function with a given name that has C linkage, but this doesn't prevent you from having a `foo` with a different signature that itself has C++ linkage.

Comment: It doesn't prevent overloading. This compiles: `extern "C" void foo(int, int);
void foo(double, int);
int main() {}`

Comment: Good point, I hadn't thought about simply declaring other C++ functions over top of it.